# The notation $\prod_{g\in G} g$ for a finite group not well-defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to solve the following exercise.

> Let $G$ be a finite group, with exactly one element $f$ of order $2$.
>   Prove that $\prod_{g\in G} g = f$.

I have a question regarding the notation, the expression $\prod_{g\in G} g$ stands for the product over all elements of $G$? But then it is not well-defined for non-abelian group, cause the order in which this product is evaluated matters? Or for what else can $\prod_{g\in G} g$ stand?

EDIT: 
I have taken the exercise from an algebra book, and I just looked up the homepage of the author and found an errata. And indeed, the exercise is wrongly stated! The group must be assumed to be abelian.

http://www.math.fsu.edu/~aluffi/algebraerrata/Errata.html

Comment: +1: Even if the group is abelian, is the product of all its elements well defined?

Comment: @Manos: Yes, an inductive definition is used.

Comment: You may be interested in Wilson's Theorem, which asserts that if $p$ is prime then $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. That is an important  special case of the result you are proving.

Comment: btw, this is a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217027

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groups with only one element of order 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237893/groups-with-only-one-element-of-order-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is wrong, not well-defined, and in fact one should assume that $G$ is abelian. Then the proof is easy by using the equivalence relation $x \sim y \Leftrightarrow x=y \vee x=y^{-1}$.

Comment: $@$Martin: could you elaborate a bit more on the proof you have in mind?

Comment: Equivalent non-equal elements cancel in the product. The only equivalence classes with one element are $\{1\}$ and $\{f\}$.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  I guess I was thinking of the converse part of the result: in a finite commutative group which does not have exactly one element of order $2$, the product of all the elements is the identity.  This is slightly harder...

Answer (score 11):

One might interpret the statement as saying that the product of all elements taken in any order gives the unique element of order $2$. But this fails for the [quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group), which has $-1$ as unique element of order $2$, while the product $1ijk(-1)(-i)(-j)(-k)$ equals $1$, not $-1$.

Comment: Moreover, the statement is false for any non-abelian group: if the value of $\prod_{g\in G} g$ doesn't depend on the order, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @Yuri Interesting, can you provide a short proof of this fact? I am lazy now...

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas If $G=\{a,b\}\sqcup H$ with $a\ne b$, the assumption is that $ab\prod_{g\in H}g=ba\prod_{g\in H}g$, so $ab=ba$. By the way, surely we know each other, right? I'm curious.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks for the answer. Your reputation (in Colombia) precedes you, so in particular I know who you are. Regarding me, this is [my answer (watch from 4:24 to 4:30)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUWKhIPT29Q)

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Hehe!

Comment: Just a comment: because the quaternion group is the smallest nonabelian group with a unique element of order 2, it gives a minimal counterexample to the OP's original claim.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the group needs to be commutative for this result to hold.  It might be nice for someone to post a minimal counterexample!  (Added: never mind: Marc van Leeuwen's answer and the comments below it take care of this.)

Because of a request from a colleague, a little while back I had the occasion to write down an excruciatingly elementary proof of this fact.  See [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/wilson_easy.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the answers, there is also a very neat answer to the question *What is the set of all different products of all the elements of a finite group $G$?* So $G$ not necessarily *abelian*. Well, if a 2-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is trivial or non-cyclic, then this set equals the commutator subgroup $G'$. If a 2-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is cyclic, then this set is the coset $xG'$ of the commutator subgroup, with $x$ the unique involution of a 2-Sylow subgroup. See also J. Dénes and P. Hermann, `On the product of all elements in a finite group', Ann. Discrete Math. 15 (1982) 105-109. The theorem connects to the theory of Latin Squares and so-called complete maps.

Comment: This is indeed a beautiful generalization.  I think I learned it from you on this site before, but I was struggling to remember the exact statement, so thanks for bringing it up again here.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the exercise from an algebra book, and I just looked up the homepage of the author and found an errata. And indeed, the exercise is wrongly stated! The group must be assumed to be abelian.

http://www.math.fsu.edu/~aluffi/algebraerrata/Errata.html

Comment: Please make this a comment to the question instead of an answer.  Better yet, edit it in to the question with a note that it has been added.